# LibGit2Sharp: UTF-16LE Encoded CSV Files Treated as Binary in Diff — How to Ensure Text Recognition?

Tags: git, .net-core, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm currently facing an issue with LibGit2Sharp when attempting to detect changes in UTF-16LE encoded CSV files. During the diff operation for uncommitted changes, LibGit2Sharp is treating these files as binary, resulting in a diff output with "Binary files differ" and 0 lines added or removed.

Here's a snippet of the problematic diff result:

```
diff --git a/test.csv b/test.csv
deleted file mode 100644
index 6e31ad9..0000000
Binary files a/test.csv and /dev/null differ
```

I've tried using the following code to retrieve the changes:

```
List<Commit> commitList = new List<Commit>();
foreach (LogEntry entry in repo.Commits.QueryBy("test.csv").Take(1).ToList())
    commitList.Add(entry.Commit);

var repoDifferences = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(commitList[0].Tree, null);
```

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: If you get the same diff output through the standard `git diff` cli command, this might be more of a `git` related question rather than a `libgit2sharp` one. Would that be the case, you may get more answers by retagging this question.